# jQuery: Execute function on document.ready() and window.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to execute a jQuery function twice. Once when the DOM is ready, and then again when the page loads. Most of the time the second call isn't necessary, but every once in a while it is.  Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function someFunction() {
        alert('function complete');
    }
});

$(window).load(function() {
    someFunction();
});​
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As said, it's a scope thing, but you could basically just move your `.load()` event binding into the DOM Ready callback function and add another call to `someFunction()` directly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are defining someFunction in the function you pass to $(document).ready()...the scope of the function should be outside it...
try this:

```
function someFunction() {
    alert('function complete');
}

$(document).ready(someFunction);
$(window).load(someFunction);​
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
function someFunction() {
    alert('function complete');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    someFunction();
});

$(window).load(function() {
    someFunction();
});
```

Comment: why pass a function that does nothing but call another function? simply pass the function you want to call!

Comment: @ParthThakkar because Google Chrome my restrict the function call, this is also good practice for cross browser development. Google Chrome advises using anon functions.

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't get you -- chrome may (that's what i think you mean) restrict the function call? how? rather, why?

Comment: @ParthThakkar yes I meant 'may' and not 'my' Google Chrome sandboxes scripts and I have found that sometimes if you do not wrap calls in anon functions it will not execute the functions, Google chrome aside, its just better practice to use recommended standards. Plus the user may want to run subsequent functions within the `$(document).ready();` with your method would not allow this.

Answer (score 2):

`someFunction` is not accessible within the `$(window).load` because it's scope is limited to the `document.ready`. Take it out of the `document.ready` and put it in the global context.

```
function someFunction() {
        alert('function complete');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     someFunction(); 
});

$(window).load(function() {
    someFunction();
});​
```